# Understanding Enums - using as constants

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

So I am trying to use enums, probably in a wrong way, as I come from PHP. in C# I have a global class which does:

```
public static class GlobalTypes
{
    public enum assignmentType { SERV = "SERV", PROD = "PROD", PER = "PER", }
}
```

From there I am trying to interact with entity by doing:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Person> getAllAgents(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new LocAppContext())
        {
            var person = (from p in db.Person
                          join la in db.LocationAssignment on p.id equals la.value
                          where la.locationID == id && la.type == GlobalTypes.assignmentType.PER
                          select p).ToList();

            return person;
        }

    }
```

But I am getting the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
>   'LocApp.Helpers.Classes.LocationAssignments.GlobalTypes.assignmentType'

Which takes place on

```
la.type == GlobalTypes.assignmentType.PER
```

my logic, and this is from php, is that I want a global constant I can call any where to "echo" out the value of that constant when called, so the constant value can change but I don't have to change it in a million places.

Ideas?

Comment: Just ditch the `= "SERV"` portions and it should be good to go. Here's some MSDN documentation on enumeration usage in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/cc138362.aspx EDIT: Also, your `la.type` should be defined as a `GlobalTypes.assignmentType` not as a string.

Comment: Enums are not strings, C# is not PHP.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair So are you saying I could do: `&& GlobalTypes.assignmentType` ?? and it will know what I want?

Comment: I think you should just use `public const` values for this, as (as people have already said) emuns in C# can't be strings (they can only be integral types: byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong).

Comment: @TheWebs No, I mean your `LocationAssignments.type` property should be typed as a `GlobalTypes.assignmentType` not as a string then your LINQ query would still look as it is (I believe). The benefit of typing against the `enum` and not as a string is it (helps to) prevent garbage data from being assigned (can't accidentally assign "ASDF" or "SomeAssignmentTypeThatDoesNotExist"). It's still _possible_ to do so, but harder (you generally have to _try_ to assign garbage data at that point)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want constant strings, then do not use enum.  Enum is for integer types.  Just use consts:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public const string PROD = "PROD";
    public const string DEV = "DEV";
}

// elsewhere...
la.type == MyClass.PROD;
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer:

```
public enum assignmentType { SERV, PROD, PER }
```

and in the comparison(assuming la.type returns a string):

```
where la.locationID == id && la.type == GlobalTypes.assignmentType.PER.ToString()
```

Comment: why wouldn't you want to do this even if you don't have to use an enum?  Using an enum sounds like a perfectly appropriate solution to this problem.

Comment: Problem: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. la.type, befor this was: la.type == "PER" so yes its a string, how ever the error still stands

Comment: Agree with @Servy.  The enum is a good solution as it is being used to group the 3 values.  Using constants as some others have suggested removes the grouping.  Perhaps use ToString and save to a temp string which is used in the query.  Having the enumeration for reuse elsewhere in the code makes sense.

Comment: I agree, comment modified.

Comment: The problem still stands @CaptainSkyhawk that I cannot use .ToString() to convert it to a string even though .type is a string.

Comment: @TheWebs see my comment and use the ToString before the LINQ statement.

Comment: @Dave you can group with constants by using the containing class as your group.  And by not using enums, you avoid all these pesky `ToString()` statements in your code, or issues with needing to assign it in a temp variable before your linq expression.  I actually prefer enums and would see about converting the source data to integral types for this purpose...but if they must be strings, it seems like using string constants is better.

Comment: @Brandon I can see if this is the only place where those values would be used that constants could be better, but depending on how these values get used elsewhere in the code base an enumeration could be better.  It is tough to judge which is better based on a small snippet.  I do agree that a containing class as a group can be a good choice depending on usage.